# Incorrect multiplication result using fixed point in C

Tags: c, casting, fixed-point

I'm trying to implement signed unsigned multiplication in C using fixed point arithmetic, but I get a incorrect result. I can't imagine how to solve this problem. I think there is some problem in the bit extension.
Here is the piece of code:

```
int16_t audio_sample=0x1FF;      //format signed Q1.8 -> Value represented=-0.00390625
uint8_t gain=0xA;                //format unsigned Q5.2 -> Value represented = 2.5
int16_t result= (int16_t)(((int16_t)((int32_t)audio_sample * (int32_t) gain);
printf("%x",result);
```

The result from `printf` is `0x13F6`, which is of course the result from `0x1FF*0xA`, but the fixed-point arithmetics said that the correct results would be `0x3FF6`, considering the proper bit-extension. `0x3FF6` in Q6.10 format represent `-0.009765625=-0.00390625*2.5` .

Please help me find my mistake.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code itself except the crazy amount of casts. `int16_t result= (int32_t)audio_sample * (int32_t) gain);` will do just fine. If you are pedantic with types you could explicitly cast the result of the multiplication to `int16_t` _once_.

Comment: How do you get that number? `Value represented=-0.00390625`

Comment: If you write `Q9.8` do you actually mean `Q1.8`?

Comment: @Gerhardh yes. I have corrected the Q format representation. Sorry I new with this kind of representation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use unsigned types here. The representation is in your head (or the comments), not in the data types in the code.

2's complement means the `1` on the left is theoretically continued forever. e.g. `0x1FF` in Q1.8 is the same as `0xFFFF` in Q8.8 (`-1 / 256`).

If you have a 16bit integer, you cannot have Q1.8, it will always be Q8.8, the machine will not ignore the other bits. So, `0x1FF` in Q1.8 should be `0xFFFF` in Q8.8. The `0xA` in Q5.2 do not change in `Q6.2`.

`0xFFFF * 0xA = 0x9FFF6`, cut away the overflow (therefore use unsigned) and you have `0xFFF6` in Q6.10, which is `-10 / 1024`, which is your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to think of fixed-point as a matter of scaling, and to express your calculation simply and clearly in terms of numbers — rather than bits. ([Example](https://godbolt.org/z/x55Kas76d))

A Q1.8 or Q5.2 number in [AMD Q notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format)) is a real number scaled by a factor of 2<sup>8</sup> or 2<sup>2</sup> respectively.

But C doesn't have 9 or 7-bit number types. Your `int16_t` and `uint8_t` variables have enough range to store such numbers. But for arithmetic operations, it is unwise to use unsigned integers, or to mix signed and unsigned types. `int` has enough range and avoids some efficiency pitfalls.

```c
int audio_sample = -0.00390625*256;  // Q1.8
int gain = 2.5*4;  // Q5.2
```

The product of numbers scaled by 2<sup>8</sup> and 2<sup>2</sup> has a scale of 2<sup>10</sup>.

```c
int result = audio_sample * gain;  // Q6.10
```

To convert back to the real value, divide by the scaler.

```c
printf("%lg * %lg = %lg\n",
    (double)audio_sample/256,
    (double)gain/4,
    (double)result/1024);
```

> Please help me find my mistake.

The mistake was in assigning `0x1FF` to `audio_sample`, instead of `-1`. `0x1FF` is the unsigned truncation of the 9-bit two's-complement value -1. But `audio_sample` is wider and would require more leading `1` bits. It would have been clearer and safer to express your intent by assigning `-0.00390625*256` to `audio_sample`.

> the fixed-point arithmetics said that the correct results would be 0x3FF6, considering the proper bit-extension

`0x3FF6` is the unsigned 14-bit truncation of the correct two's complement answer. But the result requires 16-bits so you're probably looking for value, `0xFFF6`.

```c
printf("unsigned Q6.10: 0x%x\n", (unsigned)result & 0xFFFF);
```